# Crystal Reports in Visual Studio - Can margins be dynamically changed?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I have a report where the first page has a certain top and bottom margin. Every page after that will have a different margin from the first. Is there a way to do this in Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: Do you want to alter the details, header or footer section?  And this section will be larger or smaller on page 2+?

Comment: Don't need to modify those sections. However, the content I'm trying to push down on page 2+ is in the detail section.

Comment: You need to explain this better in order to get a real answer - what is currently happening in the details section, and what do you want it to be.

Comment: The detail section is continuing onto the next page. The next page is pushing the details section down per the top margin. However, any page after page 1 I need it pushed down from the top margin PLUS a bit more (perhaps an inch. The amount is irrelevant).  Hope this explains it a bit better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume every page, except for the first, will have the same page margins?

In that case you can simply add two page headers and page footers and simply use a suppress formula such as `pagenumber = 1` and `pagenumber <> 1`.

Comment: That was going to be my suggestion, but it appears to be more complex.

Comment: Okay, after more research, I need to do this not after every page, but after every 2nd page of every record (not page). If the report has multiple records, every page after the new record needs to unsuppress the header. Ideas please?

Comment: So you have a group header (set to repeat on every page) that needs to change size on the second page? I think you could use the same approach except do it on the group headers and conditionally suppress them using the `groupnumber` keyword. I can't remember exactly how that keyword works with repeating headers...you might have to use shared variables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's in the Crystal Reports version included with Visual Studio 2008, but in the full Crystal Reports 2008 there's a new bit on the Page Setup screen for conditional margin formulas, allowing you to set the margins based on a formula.
Referenced here :

http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?t=134480